# How to get an Azure Cloud Service to suspend itself using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a azure cloud service and I want it to suspend itself once the job is complete. I have a method (below) that can suspend a cloud service from a console application, however when I place the method and call It from within the deployed cloud service it does not suspend itself.

```
    public void StopService(string serviceName, string email, string password)
    {
        using (PowerShell script = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            script.AddScript(string.Format("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString \"{0}\" -AsPlainText -Force", password));
            script.AddScript(string.Format("$userName = \"{0}\"", email));
            script.AddScript(string.Format("$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $passwprd)"));

            /*Code to sign in to azure subscription
             * ...
             * ...
            */

            script.AddScript(string.Format("$Status = (Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName \"{0}\").Status", serviceName));
            script.AddScript(string.Format("if($Status -eq \"Running\") {1} Get-AzureService -ServiceName \"{0}\" | Stop-AzureService {2}", serviceName, _bracketOpen, _bracketClose));
            script.AddScript(string.Format("(Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName \"{0}\").Status", serviceName));

            Collection<PSObject> result = script.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Can an Azure Cloud Service suspend itself or will it need to be suspended from an external service?

Comment: any specific reason to want it suspended and not deleted?

Comment: I have another PowerShell script waiting for it to transition from Running to Suspended, and then it initiates other logic

Comment: Could you give an overview of the high-level design in the question that details what the other logic is? Its unusual for a Worker Role to be started and stopped at regular intervals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more thing that you can do is you can use azure automation runbooks which keeps on monitor the status of your cloud service and stop/suspend it depending upon your requirements.

Link-

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/04/04/step-by-step-getting-started-with-windows-azure-automation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Set-AzureDeployment cmdlet instead. Here's a basic example:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Status -ServiceName "MySvc1" -Slot "Production" -NewStatus "Suspended"
```

Beware that suspending a Cloud Service does not mean you won't be paying for it. It's similar to shutting down a VM without deallocation. The only way to stop consuming resources is to remove the deployment.

**More info:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495140.aspx